# How to improve convergence while solving a large system of non linear equations

Tags: python, system, equation, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to solve a set of 10 equations with 10 unknown variables and some of the equations are non linear.

I have tried to use `fsolve` and `opt.least_squares` solvers but I have a problem of convergence, highly dependent on the value of one coefficient "alpha" and from the initial guess.

For instance:

- When alpha=1, the "cost" is around 1e-2.
- When alpha=1e3 (which I assume to be the right value), the "cost" is around 1e7.

The problem is that I don't have an idea of what could be the initial guess.
As it is a Physics project, the only thing I know is that the x_j (from 0 to 7) have to be between 0 and 3.

This is why I prefer to use `opt.least_squares` which allow me to put bounds for these parameters.

Does anyone have an idea how I could improve the initial guess with so many equations and variables ?

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt

# first set of values
C = 50.6
H = 6.5
O = 42
N = 0.2
Moist = 14.7 
FC = 19.2
ER = 0.3
Ash = 0.7
a = 1
b = 12*H/(C*1)
c = (O*12)/(C*16)
d = 0.02
M_f = 12 + 1 * b + 16 * c
M_H2O = 1 * 2 + 16
e = (Moist)/((100-Moist)*(100-Ash))*(M_f/M_H2O)
f = ER*(1+(b/4)-(c/2))
Kc = FC/C

# second set of values

alpha = 1
Gf_j = np.zeros(6, dtype=float)
Gf_j = np.array([0,-394.4,-137.3,-50.8,-237.2,0]) * alpha                          
R = 8.134                                                                       
T = 1373


# system of non linear equations

def equations(var):
    x_j = np.zeros(7, dtype=float)
    x_j[0],  x_j[1],  x_j[2],  x_j[3],  x_j[4],  x_j[5],  x_j[6],  lambda_C, lambda_O, lambda_H = var
    
    xt = sum(abs(x_j))
    eq1 = a - abs(x_j[1]) - abs(x_j[2]) - abs(x_j[3]) - abs(x_j[6])
    eq2 = b + 2*e - 4*abs(x_j[3]) - 2*abs(x_j[4]) - 2*abs(x_j[5])
    eq3 = c + e + 2*f - 2*abs(x_j[1]) - abs(x_j[2]) - abs(x_j[4])
    eq4 = d + 7.52*f - 2*abs(x_j[0])  
    eq5 = Gf_j[1] + R*T*np.log(abs(x_j[1]/xt)) + lambda_C + 2*lambda_O 
    eq6 = Gf_j[2] + R*T*np.log(abs(x_j[2]/xt)) + lambda_C + lambda_O
    eq7 = Gf_j[3] + R*T*np.log(abs(x_j[3]/xt)) + lambda_C + 4*lambda_H
    eq8 = Gf_j[4] + R*T*np.log(abs(x_j[4]/xt)) + 2*lambda_H + lambda_O
    eq9 = Gf_j[5] + R*T*np.log(abs(x_j[5]/xt)) + 2*lambda_H   
    eq10 = x_j[3] + x_j[6] - Kc

    return(eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4,eq5,eq6,eq7,eq8,eq9,eq10)




# # # use of fsolve

tt=10000
guess1 = np.array([1.2,0.3,0.4,0.1,0.3,0.4,1,tt,4*tt,0.5*tt])
sol = opt.fsolve(equations, guess1)

# display the solution
print(sol)

# check the result
x_j = np.zeros(7, dtype=float)
x_j = abs(sol[:7])
lambda_C = sol[7]
lambda_O = sol[8]
lambda_H = sol[9]
xt = sum(abs(x_j))
eq= equations(sol)



# # # use of least squares

guess = np.array([1.2,0.2,0.4,0.1,0.4,0.4,0.5,1e3,1e4,1e4])
bounds = ((1,0.1,0.1,0.02,0.1,0.1,0.1,-1e4,-1e4,-1e4), (1.5,1,1,1,1,1,2,1e5,1e5,1e5))
mod_sol2 = opt.least_squares(equations, guess, bounds = bounds)
sol2 = mod_sol2.x

# display the solution
print(sol2)

# check the result
x_j = np.zeros(7, dtype=float)
x_j = abs(sol2[:7])
lambda_C = sol2[7]
lambda_O = sol2[8]
lambda_H = sol2[9]
xt = sum(abs(x_j))
eq= equations(sol2)
print("cost:",mod_sol2.cost)
```

Thanks

Comment: Why would one ever write something like `xt = abs(sum(abs(x_j)))`?

Comment: That's a good point, it was a remnant of old script when I was adding step by step some abs() to prevent to have a negative member inside the logarithm.
But this doesn't help to solve my problem. I am now convinced that it has to do with the initial guess.

Comment: All these abs() functions, depending on the solver, can create havoc: they are non-differentiable. I tend to use variable splitting to prevent this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand much more your first comment. Therefore I have deleted every abs() functions except for the one inside the log. It doesn't seem to have an impact here.
However I have managed to improve the convergence by writing the equations from 5 to 10, in a way that x_j and lambda_ unknowns are in the same order of magnitude : 
 eq5 = Gf_j[1]/RT + np.log(abs(x_j[1]/xt)) + lambda_C + 2*lambda_O
...

If someone has an a method to have a better initial guess, I am still interested in it...